# Create Index Elasticsearch in existing sqlite relational database

Tags: python, sqlite, elasticsearch, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a web text search using python and flask. I have an existing database sqlite3.db where in my table "Post", I want to have search Blogpost index in "body". I am using sqlalchemy.

models.py

```
class Post(SearchableMixin, db.Model):
   __searchable__ = ['body']   
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)   
   body = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

For example, body contains 'Project Management, 'Engineering Management', 'Management System' and 'System Engineering'  with id =1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively etc..? My question is how we can create index or use reindex () method in existing sqlite db or mysql?

Is this a procedure? is  index ='Post ' in the example?

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es=Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200 ')
es.index(index='Post',doc_type='Post',id=1,body={'text':'Project Management'})
es.index(index='Post',doc_type='Post',id=2,body={'text':'Engineering Management'})
es.index(index='Post',doc_type='Post',id=3,body={'text':'Management System'})
es.index(index='Post',doc_type='Post',id=1,body={'text':'System Engineering'})
```

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For the existing relational database, in order to create index,go to the flask shell terminal.

```
Post.reindex()
```

And the indexes will be created..